# replace null value AND another specific value

Tags: sql

I need to list `last_name` and `pseudonym` from a table but where the `pseudonym` is null, the result should show "" and where the `pseudonym` is ending with "nen", the result should show "NEN". How can i make this into one statement?

I've come forward to this code:

```
select last_name, COALESCE(pseudonym,'') from authors
```

But I can't find out how i can make an AND statement to change the second part of the exercise. I think i need to use the LIKE statement with "nen" but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `case` expression:

```
(case when pseudonym like '%nen' then 'NEN'
      when pseudonym is not null then pseudonym
      else ''
 end) as pseudonym
```

Comment: Great answer! Makes sense now that you mention the case statement

Comment: @TehSwish . . . `case **expression**`.